# How to arrange elements vertically in pure CSS with dynamic columns?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I am trying to create a layout where elements are arranged vertically using pure CSS. If there are 2 columns and 10 items, the first five elements should be displayed in the first column, and the next five elements in the second column. If there are 11 elements, the layout should first display 6 elements in the first column and 5 elements in the second column. Is there a way to achieve this using only CSS, without resorting to JavaScript or other scripting languages?

I have tried using various CSS properties such as flex, grid, and column-count, but I couldn't find a solution that works dynamically based on the number of elements.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-2">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want half the elements in the first column whether or not that makes the first column much shorter or much taller than the second column? Ie it is solely the number of elements that matters, not their relative sizes? Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

This *does* look like a job for `column-count`, unless I'm misunderstanding the question:

```css
div {border: 1px dotted black;}

.grid-2 {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-2">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
</div>
```

If you have 10 items, there will be two equal columns, but adding an extra item means 1–6 will be in the first column.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77220717/14023394) [ralph.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031766/ralph-m) gave me is exactly what I was looking for.
Unfortunately, there is so much legacy code in the project I am involved in that any changes via CSS create problems that are difficult to deal with.

I chose JS. I created a function that replaces all elements in the array in such a way that the indexes are arranged so that the array elements are arranged in columns.

It may not be the most elegant solution, but maybe it will be useful to someone.

This is what the code looks like before applying the function:

```css
.elements {
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <div class="element">8</div>
  <div class="element">9</div>
</div>
```

This is what the code looks like after applying the function `arrangeInColumns()`:

```js
const numberOfColumns = 4;
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

var arrangedInColumns = arrangeInColumns(elements, numberOfColumns);
var elementsContainer = document.querySelector('.elements');

elementsContainer.innerHTML = '';
for (let k = 0; k < arrangedInColumns.length; k++) {
    elementsContainer.appendChild(arrangedInColumns[k]);
}


function arrangeInColumns(elements, numberOfColumns) {
    const rows = Math.floor(elements.length / numberOfColumns);
    const extraItems = elements.length % numberOfColumns;

    const tableHeight = rows + extraItems;

    const newArrayForElements = [];

    let currentIndex = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < tableHeight; i++) {
        const rowOffset = i;
        let valuesToAdd = 0;

        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
            if (currentIndex === elements.length) break;

            const newIndex = rowOffset + valuesToAdd;
            newArrayForElements[currentIndex] = elements[newIndex];

            valuesToAdd += rows;
            if (extraItems > j) {
                valuesToAdd += 1;
            }

            currentIndex++;
        }
    }
    return newArrayForElements;
}
```

```css
.elements {
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <div class="element">8</div>
  <div class="element">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.grid-2 {
  column-count: 2;
  max-width: none;
  column-gap: 0; 
}
.item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-2 {
column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

this css will help you

[for large display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbtWd.png)

[for mbl screen display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NknsG.png)

Comment: I can’t see how this ensures there are (n+1)/2 items in the first column if the items are of different sizes.

Comment: .grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
  max-width: none;
  column-gap: 0;
} use this for same left and right sizes.

Comment: or you can arrange item size